# How To Transfer Data from a Table View Cell to a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

In my app I have a row of table view cells, each with a stepper and three labels. The stepper changes the value of a label in a table view cell. The problem I am facing is that when I try to transfer this data to the view controller the table view is on it does not transfer the data. I need each cell in the table view to give me a specific value so I have the code for the table view cell set up like this set up like this.

```
import UIKit

 class ItemSearchCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBAction func itemAmountChanger(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    itemQuantyWanted.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
    SearchResults().itemResultsAmountWanted.insert(Int(sender.value), at: position)
}


@IBOutlet weak var amountChangerValue: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var areaView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var itemPrice: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var itemQuantyWanted: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

 }
```

I then take this data and transfer it to a new viewcontroller when a button on the viewcontroller with the tableview is pressed. However the data is not sent by the stepper. The code used for sending the data is this.

```
var itemResultsName:[String]=[]
var itemResultsAmountWanted:[Int]=[]

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let nextView = segue.destination as! CategorsSearch
    if segue.identifier == "Return"{
        if itemResults.count != 0{
            for i in 0 ... (itemResults.count-1){
                nextView.returningItemsName.append(itemResultsName[i])
                nextView.returningItemsAmountWanted.append(itemResultsAmountWanted[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is how do I transfer data from a table view cell to a view controller that the table view is on without the use a seugeway.

I am using the latest version of xcode 8.

Comment: FYI - regarding your use of Xcode 8 - You need to use Xcode 9 soon. See https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05072018a

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you modeled your project.

Let's describe the problem.

You need a list and the list is a representation from a some data source, like Array. If you have an array you can match the selectedIndex from list and get the value from array.

In the TableView you have delegates, and this delegate return how cell was selected with id, so get this id and get the data from your array.

I hope to help you to find the solution

Comment: I can confirm, didn't find way to get data from cell directly, only from arrays, that fill cells